# RxJs: Abort a deferred and shared observable when all unsubscribe

Tags: javascript, typescript, rxjs, observable, reactivex

I want to create an `rxjs` `Observable` that runs a long polling operation.
Each iteration emits intermediate results.
When `isComplete` returns true, the `Observable` completes.

This function should behave as follows

1. It should start only when there's **at least one subscriber**
2. It should **allow multiple subscribers** to share the results
3. It should abort the polling and call cancel if there are **no subscribers** left

The following code works properly and satisfies conditions (1) and (2):

```
function longPollingAction(fetch: () => Promise<Response>, cancel: () => {}): Observable<Response> {
   return defer(() => { // defer to start running when there's a single subscriber
     return from(fetch()).pipe(
         expand(() => timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(fetch))),
         takeWhile<Response>(isComplete, false),
    );
   }).pipe(share()); // share to allow multiple subscribers
}

function isComplete(r: Response): boolean {
   // returns true if r is complete. 
}
```

How can I modify this code to satisfy (3) as well? With the current implementation the polling stops, but how do I call `cancel`?

Comment: I think share already behaves this way? If not, try `.pipe(publish(), refCount())`.

Comment: @MrkSef you are right. Polling does stop with the current implementation. I fixed my question: I want to call a `cancel` function when there are no subscribers left.

Comment: I've added an answer below. You should be able to just use `finalize`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using Finalize

You can call cancel using `finalize`. Here's how that might look:

```ts
function longPollingAction(
  fetch: () => Promise<Response>,
  cancel: () => void
): Observable<Response> {
  // defer to turn eager promise into lazy observable
  return defer(fetch).pipe( 
    expand(() => timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(fetch))),
    takeWhile<Response>(isComplete, false),
    finalize(cancel),
    share() // share to allow multiple subscribers
  );
}

function isComplete(r: Response): boolean {
   // returns true if r is complete. 
}
```

#### Callback on `complete`

The tap operator has access to `next`, `error`, and `complete` emissions. For a `callback: () => void`, that's good enough.

```ts
function longPollingAction(
  fetch: () => Promise<Response>,
  cancel: () => void
): Observable<Response> {
  // defer to turn eager promise into lazy observable
  return defer(fetch).pipe( 
    expand(() => timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(fetch))),
    takeWhile<Response>(isComplete, false),
    tap({
      complete: cancel
    }),
    share() // share to allow multiple subscribers
  );
}

function isComplete(r: Response): boolean {
   // returns true if r is complete. 
}
```

#### Callback on `unsubscribe`

I don't **think** such an operator exists, but we can make one easily enough. This operator will only fire the callback if unsubscribed. It will ignore `error`, and `complete`.

```ts
function onUnsubscribe<T>(
  fn: () => void
): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<T> {
  return s => new Observable(observer => {
    const bindOn = name => observer[name].bind(observer);
    const sub = s.subscribe({
      next: bindOn("next"),
      error: bindOn("error"),
      complete: bindOn("complete")
    });
   
    return {
      unsubscribe: () => {
        fn();
        sub.unsubscribe()
      }
    };
  });
}
```

Then you can use it like this:

```ts
function longPollingAction(
  fetch: () => Promise<Response>,
  cancel: () => void
): Observable<Response> {
  // defer to turn eager promise into lazy observable
  return defer(fetch).pipe( 
    expand(() => timer(1000).pipe(switchMap(fetch))),
    takeWhile<Response>(isComplete, false),
    onUnsubscribe(cancel),
    share() // share to allow multiple subscribers
  );
}

function isComplete(r: Response): boolean {
   // returns true if r is complete. 
}
```

Since `share` is managing your subscriptions and share will only unsubscribe once `refCount < 1`, then the only way to call cancel in this case is to have no subscribers.

Comment: `finalize` would get called when the stream completes as well. Not only when execution was halted.

Comment: It also gets called on error. All of which cause your long-polling to be halted.

Comment: I've updated this answer with a few more options.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way to skin a cat, but this is how I would do it:

```
const onUnsubscribe = (callback: () => void) => <T>(source$: Observable<T>) =>
  new Observable<T>(observer => {
    let isSourceDone = false;

    const subscription = source$.subscribe(
      val => {
        observer.next(val);
      },
      e => {
        isSourceDone = true;
        observer.error(e);
      },
      () => {
        isSourceDone = true;
        observer.complete();
      }
    );

    return () => {
      if (isSourceDone) return;
      callback();
      subscription.unsubscribe();
    };
  });

function longPollingAction(
  fetch: () => Promise<Response>,
  cancel: () => {}
): Observable<Response> {
  const lazyFetch$ = defer(() => fetch());
  return lazyFetch$.pipe(
    expand(() => timer(1000).pipe(mergeMapTo(lazyFetch$))),
    takeWhile<Response>(isComplete, false),
    onUnsubscribe(cancel),
    share()
  );
}

function isComplete(r: Response): boolean {
  // returns true if r is complete.
}
```